# How to determine the length used with group concat of MySQL query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySQL [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and I'm worry about exceeding the `group_concat_max_len` value, default is 1024, so I need a way let me to know how much a specific `SELECT` query used from allowed length of that property?

For instance suppose the following query:

```
'SELECT duration, defect_id, defects.title, caves FROM ('
                . 'SELECT SUM('
                     . 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,GREATEST(:startDate, ca.created_at),LEAST(:endDate,IFNULL(ca.closed,NOW())))'
                    . ') AS duration, ca.defect_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cavity_id) as caves FROM cavity_actions as ca WHERE'
                    . ' ca.job_id = :job_id AND ca.defect_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ca.defect_id'
                . ') AS durations'               
                . ' LEFT JOIN defects ON durations.defect_id = defects.id '

                . 'ORDER BY duration DESC';
```

My application is built using [laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4) and I'm using `DB::select()` so if there a way to set `group_concat_max_len` dynamically using Laravel it will also be better. However, I have full access to the database server and I can to set `group_concat_max_len` permanently.

Comment: I think the best suggestion would be don't use GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by running

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cavity_actions WHERE ca.job_id = job_id AND ca.defect_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ca.defect_id
```

And seeing how many results came in from that. If that exceeds the limit of group_concat_max_len then you can query for subsets of your target data and then join the results in the end.

Comment: I think that proprty is tends for size in bytes not the count of query rows